# RadEditor. How can I get the full HTML on the server?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radeditor

I tried using the `Content` property but that only gives me the `div` containing the edited content.  I need the full html that contains the div.

I know there is a `get_html()` method for client side, but is there any equivalent for server side?

I also tried `.GetHtml(EditorStripHtmlOptions.None)` but that returns the same thing as the `Content` property.

I looked on http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/methods_t_telerik_web_ui_radeditor.html
but don't see anything else there that can help me.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: `.Content` will return to you all of the HTML content that was in the RadEditor. It can't return the HTML of the entire page (the stuff surrounding the RadEditor). Is that what you are trying to get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MikeSmithDev is correct.  .Content is indeed returning the full HTML after I set it to the full HTML